# jquery to get value from looping not working

Tags: jquery, click

i have problem when i want to get value with jquery from looping. this my code

```
<?php 
  for($x=0; $x < count($results); $x++){
?>
    <span id="delete">Delete</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="comm" name="comm" value="<?=$results[$x]['id'];?>">
<?php
  }
?>
```

and this my jquery code

```
$("#delete").click(function() { 
   var comm = $("#comm").val();
   alert(comm);
});
```

with this condition, when i click "Delete", first time i get value but when i click again i dont get anything value

Comment: Id has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your code so that id is not repeated:

```
<?php 
  for($x=0; $x < count($results); $x++){
?>
    <span class="delete">Delete</span>
    <input type="hidden" class="comms" id="comm<?php echo $x; ?>" name="comm<?php echo $x?>" value="<?=$results[$x]['id'];?>">
<?php
  }
?>
```

Now, in your javascript code:

```
$(".delete").click(function() { 
   var comm = $(this).find("+ input").val();
   alert(comm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are selecting the first element with id `delete`. ID's must be unique on your page.

I see that you are using hidden input only to get its value. If you are using it for this purpose only, you can omit it and just add data to your delete button as `data-*` attribute.

**PHP:**

```
<?php for($x=0; $x < count($results); $x++){ ?>
    <span class="delete" data-id="<?=$results[$x]['id'];?>">Delete</span>
<?php } ?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".delete").click(function() { 
   var comm = $(this).data('id');
   alert(comm);
});
```

The advantage is that if your ID is number, it will be casted for you as well.